# Filter Sharepoint View

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What's the least painful way to filter a least of people by their age

e.g. only show people over the age of 60 based on their birthday

Answer (score 1):

Use a Content Query web part.

Assuming a Date field called DOB, add the content query web part to a page and edit the web part. Expand the query section and add your list to `Show items from the following list`.

Then under `Additional Filters` > `Show items when:` select `DOB` field and `is less than or equal to` and in `Custom Value or Query` enter -21915 then click Ok and the web part should show people over the age of 60.

Comment: I actually did this in the end by editing the view query in SPD by adding the following:

<Query>
  <Where>
    <Leq>
     <FieldRef Name="DOB"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime">
        <Today OffsetDays="-21915"/>
      </Value>
   </Leq>
  </Where>
</Query>